# Deep dive Azure Log analytics cost using KQL query

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I'm running following Log Analytics Kusto query to get data what uses and thus generetes our Log Analytics cost

```
 Usage 
 | where IsBillable == true
 | summarize BillableDataGB = sum(Quantity) by Solution, DataType
 | sort by Solution asc, DataType asc
```

and then the output is following:
[image]

What kinda query should I use if I want to deep dive more eg to ContainerInsights/InfrastructureInsights/ServiceMap/VMInsights/LogManagement so to get more detailed data what name or namespaces really cost?

Insightmetrics table have e.g these names and namespaces.

[image]

I was able maybe able to get something out using following query but something is still missing. Not totally sure if I'm on right or wrong way

```
union withsource = tt *
| where _IsBillable == true
| extend Namespace, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for getting the name and namespace details. using Kusto query

```
let startTimestamp = ago(1h);
KubePodInventory
| where TimeGenerated > startTimestamp
| project ContainerID, PodName=Name, Namespace
| where PodName contains "name" and Namespace startswith "namespace"
| distinct ContainerID, PodName
| join
(
    ContainerLog
    | where TimeGenerated > startTimestamp
)
on ContainerID
// at this point before the next pipe, columns from both tables are available to be "projected". Due to both
// tables having a "Name" column, we assign an alias as PodName to one column which we actually want
| project TimeGenerated, PodName, LogEntry, LogEntrySource
| summarize by TimeGenerated, LogEntry
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

For more information you can go through the [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-log-query#pods-by-name-and-namespace) and here is the [Kust Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorial?pivots=azuredataexplorer) Tutorial.